# union access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

i have union question on access.

i have table MyCount

```
S | A | M | Q
=============
1 |10 |111| 4
1 |10 |222| 5
1 |10 |333| 9
1 |20 |444|10
```

I have table Catalog

```
S | A | M | 
=============
1 |10 |111| 
1 |10 |222| 
1 |10 |333| 
1 |10 |444|
1 |10 |555|
1 |20 |999|
1 |20 |888|
1 |20 |777|
```

i need all the data from MyCount with the Catalog - but if data on MyCount

not in Catalog, it will came with Qty=0

i need union query that the resault will looks like this:

```
S | A | M | Q
=============
1 |10 |111| 4 
1 |10 |222| 5 
1 |10 |333| 9 
1 |10 |444| 0
1 |10 |555| 0
1 |20 |999|10
1 |20 |888| 0
1 |20 |777| 0
```

Comment: *but if data on MyCount not in Catalog* ... please describe the two table's relations. Is it S and A and M? If so, why is M=999 with Q=10? And why is M=444 with Q=0? Both should be zero if S/A/M are the related keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all`:

```
select s, a, m, q
from mycount
union all
select s, a, m, 0
from catalog as c
where not exists (select 1
                  from mycount as mc
                  where mc.s = c.s and mc.a = c.a and mc.m = c.m
                 );
```